# Why are the granules of pancreatic beta cells larger than those of alpha cells?

Tags: histology

Why are the granules (insulin) of β cells larger than the granules (glucagon) in α cells in pancreatic islets of Langerhans?

Also is there any size difference between alpha cells and beta cells?

Source: Inderbir Singh , Text book of Human Histology. Ed 8. Ch-16. Pg 202.

Comment: This may help: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2909340/#!po=55.1282  smaller granules=>more precision. Large granules=> more economy is excreting large quantities.

Comment: May be thats the case here as well as..